# Loading Screen using Thread not finishing when MessageBox opens right after it ends

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently having problems with a loading screen that uses the Thread system. When some dialog opens during the thread operation or right after it, the thread does not finish, unless i close the dialog first. Any ideas how this can be solved?

```
private bool _done;
private Action _method;

public FrmLoading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public FrmLoading(Action methodLoading, string info) : this()
{
    _method = methodLoading;
    lblStatus.Text = info;
}

private event EventHandler LoadingConcluded;

private void OnLoadingConcluded()
{
    LoadingConcluded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void ExecuteMethod()
{
    _method();
    OnLoadingConcluded();
}

public void ExecuteThread(params object[] objs)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowLoadingScreen));
    thread.Start();

    LoadingConcluded += (o, ex) =>
    {
        _done = true;
    };

    ExecuteMethod();
}

private void ShowLoadingScreen()
{
    MinimizeBox = false;
    MaximizeBox = false;
    ControlBox = false;

    Text = "";
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    BackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 45);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
    {
        Show();
        while (!_done)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? WebForms? Or something else?

Comment: Windows Forms App

Comment: I think the issue is that your `tread.Start()` could finish before you register the `LoadingConcluded` eventhandler. Can you test if moving `tread.Start` after the event handler helps? Can you also tell us which version of .NET you're using? Manually creating and managing threads should no longer be necessary in modern versions of .NET.

Comment: Pretty much a testimonial for why it is such a bad idea to display UI on a worker thread.  The thread isn't STA so any automation software could deadlock, no guarantee that the user can see the window since it doesn't have an owner, the worker burns 100% core, a race condition in the event subscription, a bool is not a synchronization primitive so the while-loop never ending in the Release build is expected (use ManualResetEventSlim), closing the window manually doesn't fix anything with the worker continuing to run.  Don't do it, UI belongs on the UI thread and slow code belongs on a worker.

Comment: How do i separate the UI splash screen from the worker thread?